# Loop 4 array elements. then break. then loop the 4 next array elements, and so on until end of array

Tags: php, arrays, output

My array contains a dynamic amount of element.
they are grouped in 4. so

```
array
 [0] -> "group one"
 [1] -> "group one"
 [2] -> "group one"
 [3] -> "group one"

 [4] -> "group two"
 [5] -> "group two"
 [6] -> "group two"
 [7] -> "group two"

 [8] -> "group three"
 [9] -> "group three"
 [10] -> "group three"
 [11] -> "group three"
```

What I want to do is output and test all the elements i each group in one loop, add  then do the same with the next group.

I suspect it should be easy.. using a counter to keep track of how many outputs etc, but apparently my brain wont work properly on this problem :)

Thanks to anyone who bothers helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
<?php
foreach(array_chunk(range(1, 12), 4) as $index => $chunk) {
    echo "Printing Chunk $index\n";
    foreach($chunk as $number) {
        echo "$number\n";
    }
}

/*
    Printing Chunk 0
    1
    2
    3
    4
    Printing Chunk 1
    5
    6
    7
    8
    Printing Chunk 2
    9
    10
    11
    12
*/
```

Anthony.

Comment: Note: If you want to preserve keys, pass True as the third argument.

Comment: array_chunk() !! Fantastic :D
so many functions I need to know exist!
Thanks alot, A.S !

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$length = count($array);

// the first element of each group is indexed by $i
// so the second element can be accessed by $i + 1, the third by $i + 2, ...
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i += 4)
{
    echo "1. element: " . $array[$i];
    echo "2. element: " . $array[$i+1];
    echo "3. element: " . $array[$i+2];
    echo "4. element: " . $array[$i+3];

    // do something
}

?>
```